# #intershop 7.10 publish corporate distribution on nexus doesn't work

Tags: installation, nexus, intershop

I am trying to set up a development environment, so I started following intershop tutorial: Prepare Your Artifact Repository Server (https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/287Q77).

when I run

```
[vagrant@localhost corporate-distribution]$ ./gradlew publish -PreleaseURL=http://localhost:8081/nexus/content
/repositories/distributions -PscmVersionExt=REALEASE
```

nothing is published on the nexus even though I get a message that the build is successful

```
:publish UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

when I run with

```
[vagrant@localhost corporate-distribution]$ ./gradlew publish -PrunOnCI=true -PreleaseURL=http://localhost:808
1/nexus/content/repositories/distributions -PscmVersionExt=REALEASE

All tasks will be executed on a CI build environment.

:downloadGradle

:customGradleDistribution

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not expand ZIP '/home/vagrant/intershop-cisetup-sources/devops/gradle/corporate-distribution/gradle-downloads/gradle-2.11-bin.zip'.
> archive is not a ZIP archive

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I verified the zip file :

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 vagrant vagrant 0 Nov  8 16:52 gradle-2.11-bin.zip
```

so I downloaded one manually and added it to gradle-downloads folder.  the same thing .. I always get the :publish UP-TO-DATE .

Any ideas will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please use block code to format your code correctly? As it is, it's difficult to read through.

Comment: PscmVersionExt=REALEASE should be PscmVersionExt=RELEASE

Answer (score 2):

The reason is a (new) redirect from `http://services.gradle.org/distributions` to `https://services.gradle.org/distributions`.

Please change your gradle distribution URLs to https.

Affected files: `corporate-ditribution/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`, `corporate-distribution/build.gradle`

Comment: The issue is now fixed on the latest version of https://github.com/IntershopCommunicationsAG/intershop-cisetup-template